# Terminal server (ser2net) to configure new HP procurve switch

Tags: linux, networking, router, serial-console

Switch: HP ProCurve 2910AL-48G - J9147A

This switch is brand new straight from HP.

Anyone familiar with ser2net for creating a terminal server to connect from usb>serial>console port on a HP procurve switch? I've done this 4 times in the past couple months and had 0 issues. This exact same new one isn't working.

Guides I used as a reference:
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=3901671&prodTypeId=12883&prodSeriesId=3901671&objectID=c01975721
http://www.gns3.net/switching-how-to-console-into-your-devices/

```
root@mycomp:/dev# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0557:2008 ATEN International Co., Ltd UC-232A Serial Port [pl2303]

root@mycomp:/dev# dmesg | grep tty
[ 0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[ 0.738224] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[ 0.963603] 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[16153.422206] usb 1-1.1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[18163.982680] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[18167.091054] usb 1-1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0

/etc/ser2net.conf
3002:telnet:0:/dev/ttyUSB0:9600 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT banner

root@mycomp -> telnet localhost 3002
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

ser2net port 3002 device /dev/ttyUSB0 [9600 N81] (Debian GNU/Linux)
```

Then it just hangs there, doesn't take me to a prompt as it did in the past with other brand new switches. If you type anything you get:

Connection closed by foreign host.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? Also if there is a better way of doing this, feel free to inform me, I have 3 new switches that ideally need to be deployed by end of day tomorrow.

Comment: not sure if it's any better, but check out `conserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this problem when I enabled HW flow control (RTSCTS) on my configuration line in the `/etc/ser2net` config file. You can disable this by adding `-RTSCTS` to the line.

I also had the issue that my session would immediately disconnect with:

> Connection closed by foreign host.

I solved this by adding "LOCAL" to the configuration line which ignores the modem monitoring lines.